# How to aquire a Kerberos ticket for a different user?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, kerberos

Is there a way to retrieve a Kerberos ticket for a different domain user from Azure AD? A scenario would be to use OAuth2 in a web application and have this application connect to a SQL Server as the web-user.

1. User abc@mydomain.com contacts website with the browser
2. The website sends back error 401 (Unauthorized) and a header asking for Bearer Token Authentication ("`WWW-Authenticate: Bearer`")
3. OAuth2 is done on the client site using the browser by contacting the OAuth authority (e.g. Azure Active Directory for mydomain.com).
4. The user contacts the website again, now using an auth header in the HTTP request ("`Authorization: Bearer ey...`").
5. The web server now contacts the Kerberos Domain Controller (which might have to be an Active Directory) saying "please give me a Kerberos ticket for abc@mydomain.com. Here is the OAuth Bearer token that user just sent me to prove that I should do this now."
6. The KDC trusts the web server (and the account under which it is running) and sends back a Kerberos ticket.
7. The web server uses the freshly received Kerberos ticket to log in to SQL Server as user abc@mydomain.com.

Steps 5 to 7 can be replaced by using the user's credentials (for example stored in a [keytab](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/keytab_def.html)) to request a Kerberos ticket from the KDC. But I wonder if this can be achieved by *transferring* the authentication from one type to the other (so from OAuth2 token to Kerberos ticket) rather then by storing user credentials.

[Microsoft's Power BI Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/de-de/gateway/) seems to do this. A technical user is used to connect to the SQL Server. This user appears to be able to retrieve a Kerberos ticket for any other domain user. The gateway checks user identities by OAuth2 authentication. So I assume the whole process is based on trust to the technical user and/or Azure AD trusting the OAuth2 token.

Unfortunately I was not able to find specific documentation on this. What permissions would be required?

Comment: You can make use of a specific identity provider (IDP). In OAuth you can specify different identity providers (login+password, google, facebook to log into a single site, for example). If you would create your own IDP, you could check the identity in the sql db and connect your IDP to your Azure AD.

Comment: There's a protocol referred to as "protocol transition" or S4U-Proxy which does this. In Windows it's called constrained delegation with "any protocol".

Comment: As far as I understand constrained delegation can be used once a Kerberos ticket is around. So if I log in to a web application using Kerberos and this web application is running in a user context for which (on that machine) constrained delegation is enabled, the web application can log in to a SQL server impersonating me. 

I am struggling to get the first Kerberos ticket (which has to come from the Domain Controller) on the base of an OAuth ticket used for the login.